# In gbc.insets(_,_,_,_), what do the four numbers inside of the brakets mean in java?

Tags: java, numbers, gridbaglayout

I was wondering what the four numbers inside the brackets of the `insets` property of `GridBagConstrains` mean. Here's the part of it:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.insets = new Insets(12,12,18,18);
```

Inside of those brackets, what do they mean?  I've been wondering for, I think, litterally ***ages.*** I was guessing size of spaces... idek.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html#constructor.summary

Comment: Take a look at the [JavaDocs for `insets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Insets javadoc API, the four blanks specify how much padding you'd want for your elements. First parameter is how much padding you want for the bottom part of your element, second parameter is for the left, third is for the right, fourth is for the top.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html